# What does Europe have in common with Timon and Pumbaa?

Tags: cipher

The answer is a five-letter English word, but "give me a hint" you might say. Unscramble the non-English text below, and you will be well on your way to solving this riddle. Just don't let `jkc sßW rJTß gLOBsRuuprwe uöIN bNfs ävErgG KvUpAdcIsnä MZx üzc oßxhvs dRMäD saaUeof fxHz KNbK VxJkck KGwjöb fb` get you down, or the oracle behind [the matrix](https://gist.github.com/Blastus/e039a8dffdb6b15b36fb) will refuse to reveal her secrets.

**Hint 1:** It seems that something was missing, and so that missing piece has been added to the place it belongs. Maybe by comparing past revisions of this riddle something important will become evident. In the mean time, take note that space and newline characters were not touched during encryption.

**Hint 2:** A few more changes have been introduced to the riddle. Check the matrix to see its new design and its previous contents. Look at the revision history for this question to see what has changed and the extent of those edits. The message now has unencrypted punctuation characters.

**Hint 3:** Oh no! The same problem has been discovered that was present with the very first version of this riddle. The old, German poem was missing something at the beginning that should have been there in the first place. Can you compare the various revisions to understand the message better?

**Hint 4:** [Cerberus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13268) has correctly identified [the poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice) which correlates with Europe. Now want does the poem have in common with Timon and Pumbaa? Try to answer "what is everywhere?" As a bonus, try to identify who [the matrix](https://gist.github.com/Blastus/e039a8dffdb6b15b36fb) is. She has attributes in common with Timon, Pumbaa, and the poem.

```
pUo xfDnkduvsBJhAJ
muTßUo ZGhfOGoe MkI ktgoRz

MGk iöv RLAM hkzAjfktzOKn
Demu vacS jsLkMx RTwrbSüNGL!
ORa fcG gnSgih äIäls cTGksüF
gööB lMTF dLhgmi eIZUZD mfoxd.
djOtß VTkF öRc ZhHZg
äuhVe öEh uZh fOW keüVzg,
GOK xnA RMGeOxSDOcLDw
LD ZRh HzmrtK hzßV.

SßBpw! oLJuN
VKnznk ähJozwJ,
ähi, vEr MMSvZD,
FenZhs WGUSxz
BAE fdk jLxIKRD, bVDutZ vzZnLbhJ
TE MJl zojh EKGk udSlLßo.

SSO äNi Gvwü, eA MIVVK öUHGa,
zRhi LDg lmIHgouLcS ZJDNuKNdSiex!
RMMA jBtVu GGvah IOGNRk blRJuFG:
Ima JßLGAEä puiwöO gHhNIn!
Szp Wwwm DiJjFN ääigf,
RTZb Ivg VmW ceüü,
zfzv RpG öVU cäpM
cmI dma gRzgöNzxDu!

ögUeH! lSöoW
eEeLnk HoSsfAs,
ZBg, ügt DigAnm,
wAAssu söBwRW
üSI TAg OnfhDEd, DMoZKö zhIIStwV
Tf VJA Ruxp WFäb wpcVBoo.

ldAw, dL VLAuG pSd nHfo xMDdcU!
VOBßhhßF! tvs oJmJe vb KxK cdäLgz,
par Tgt brZbkwNznAnxRNm ALoxvn
lwd fV ijdT MGx aOzWUtJ pIAcM.
WLccp Dzx iZblJoi rfNT!
exN Doh xtNTar SmxjvZov!
pko üDßz rViE fWWsMz
IsWs VBu HptwHj äLwLD!

üUpVh! nZMxH!
jswS Kpj ütJeo
hGvösp Umbje
iowüTiürßKos! -
fIV, HMT fbmJ dö! öRcr! zHOO!
RNK nuz lakx FBA vWOu GboSIüJOl!

JmZ, ücL ovpA, wßMrßN Be ZäJa
Ki uiS wujI, luL Mf MLjäeJn!
hNs, ud MHSSI lLD sLhgWK sRvIrdV!
Mzöac Rn ßiUü bTk LWpd NhWvö!
GVfTH bINF hFWrD
dHFDRf zx RxWpbJU jkmüGA,
böd, lgU cüLNsMr üäEkRR
jTjsacp Luö Fmjd ADF!

jxäL, lüOID oukaMV
gmIN üsäk ieIHhx:
WdKä zAü TMnmUS!
KuW OVl ukjcN!
RZc, wuu BZju Fwö IDRhf ZTIdaß!
UJuäxe iJTjT! WLöcMh öOftuK!

n, iu müjuclKsS pFU SnMmp!
MnGo NoW tRüTK twwA DaVjhMek?
hBm Wpw nWIp Sfwz jfZIeHßW
efkJ üEcöR KtnäKcbVhäLt iKämuO.
rrv AhGßLrJBzö zulmü, 
MgM OzIMw tWDKk cKül!
xöUrE, pöe HE toSRcOR,
bhän cxIw FJödtj ZßöWR!

RKtdlL bh Kllg
SMö DDxäS ZxhZaL?
nbVb IpZH wävcxW,
vaKW KlEe sZMLäD
Ika ödK Fößv NIFO WäuERJE
TEM weH ßehcZKGt paShU JzHsüßk!

eeDe, eß Wrbol IL LBBpphöJnG oHäAIF!
TZä URZ REkf üHO rcc DsMd uKWGä,
wäELRb, p wHkNuo, KBzwIT ßä ZKOTco;
NZvxtMcM cfWTVd eEz iHOKZM ffüjerR.
wLzTxlMB! WoFh vMvcpOMFd! 
zWcH, rK FaB ßErdorV!
MBl TzL jATM cEk aknaWV,
IgA üüL Rtgü Fohü!

bjiv! Aögv!
BfkVd eäUmE
eövmA fc onHl
evvOK Hzm iFßiVSn
öämUjs tSLrlg am KMS pTpn!
aZlgN RIS, tsR! Twu llnüö jNpkWM!

WJV jAh BLHMwä! üäc Drj RoüßjZ
hAßjx NK ZHTB MOb iAf KIk äaphnß:
WJafü uüVxVTBLwsHrE äBakTDTn!
nhhg uWT JcalUZU, jaL ZVIU efwfS! -
Bnl, wB ngWpI jZü Ahfbnxz!
dRfß, jSn nvä dwö dLDj!
scD JdI dVsA, Kßz gONIövi,
tdwj rxk mhG rTztD Kze.

"Kh FaM Ardl,
AVses! kSIbk!
SNZBn öURkEle!
WHän Bnp äFbuAjJ
USUF iekK Jfv, xm iVgxaV cnkuZä,
bTFn jKJOMk pUB wäsE aOßjinä."
```

Comment: Can you copy the pastebin contents here? Some of us are behind firewalls that block it.

Comment: @EngineerToast Can you access GitHub through your proxy? The matrix has been copied into a gist.

Comment: I can access GitHub. I don't know if others have any trouble, though. Now I see why you called it a matrix.

Comment: It means "no worries for the rest of your days".

Comment: Question: when you say "non-English text", are you talking about the decrypted text too?

Comment: @Aioros Yes, the decrypted text comes from a European language. If you translate the answer into this language, only the last letter will be different.

Comment: @kaine The poem behind the ciphertext may describe a fictional story, but none of the people working for Disney would be credited for its authorship.

Comment: Ok, I'm totally stumped here, so I'll share the only useful thing I have: the "matrix" is composed of 22 lines, and each line is a permutation of the same 56 characters. I can't figure out how to proceed, though.

Comment: @Aioros It may be helpful to figure out what language the poem is written in. Taking note of repeated text could also contribute to solving the riddle.

Comment: Well, the obvious guess would be German, but I'm afraid that doesn't really help much.

Comment: I will add a few notes for anyone trying to make a sense of the poem: the alphabet is obviously German; character frequencies seem to exclude a (simple) substitution cipher; Vigenère is also unlikely, since there is basically no repetition at all, except for the second and fourth stanzas that are almost identical.

Comment: No worries for the rest of your days? Hakuna Matata confirmed.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Both the words "Hakuna" and "Matata" have six letters in them. The answer to this riddle is one word having exactly five letters in it.

Comment: Has the poem been created for this puzzle, or is it an already existing one?

Comment: @Aioros The poem was written within 10 years of AD 1800 and should be well known in the cultures that speak the language in which it was written.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

Just by looking at the format, and the last comment by the OP, the poem talked about is

> [Der Zauberlehrling by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe](http://germanstories.vcu.edu/goethe/zauber_dual.html)

Hopefully this helps someone else to solve the puzzle.

Comment: ahh, now I want to watch Fantasia again.

Comment: could the matrix be referring to [Philopseudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice) then, since the title says "An Egyptian Spirit"??